# Display an archives name

Tags: archives

I want to display the current archives name, so for the url below I could do something like this

```
<h1><?php echo "answer" ?></h1>
```

which would output something like this

```
<h1>News</h1>
```

or better yet

```
<h1>News: supplierName</h1>
```

http://www.site.com/suppliers/news/?supplierstax=supplierName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you need:

```
<?php if (is_category()) { // Show only on Category archive pages ?>
<h1><?php echo single_cat_title('News: '); ?></h1>

<?php } elseif (is_tag()) { // Show only on Tag archive pages ?>
<h1><?php echo single_tag_title('News: '); ?></h1>

<?php } ?>
```

OR like this (as @StephenHarris [pointed out](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56945/display-an-archives-name#comment73251_56946)):

```
<h1><?php
    if ( is_category() || is_tag() ) {
        single_term_title( 'News: ', false );
    }
?></h1>
```

Comment: See inside `wp_title` (see [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-includes/general-template.php#L528)) for similar functions. Many take a prefix as an argument, e.g. `'News: '` in the OP's question.

Comment: Yup - but I was just linking there in case others need to find a similar function for a different context :)